# Codigniter MySQL data row sum returns 0.00

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used the following table in my Codeigniter project to view some amounts in MySQL.
[image]

If I select header checkbox or row checkbox I want to get sum of ammounts under Total row.
I used the following codes :

```
<tr class="" style="background-color: #33ffcc !important;">
  <th><input id="selectAll" type="checkbox" /></th>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Ref No</th>
  <th>Descrition</th>
  <th>Transfered To</th>
  <th>Amount (Rs.)</th>
  <th>Approved Amount (Rs.)</th>
  <th>Current Status</th>
  <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tfoot>
    <tr class="" style="background-color: #00cc99 !important;">
        <td colspan="<?= $type ? 5 : 6 ?>">Total</td>
        <td id="request_total"  class="text-right" ></td>            
        <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<script>
$('#selectAll').change(function(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        $(".selected").prop("checked", true)
        $('.amount').map((key,ele) => {
            total += parseFloat(ele.value.replaceAll(",",""))
        })
        showForm()
    } else {
        total = 0
        $(".selected").prop("checked", false)
        hideForm()
    }
    $('#request_total').text(numberWithCommas(total.toFixed(2)))    
})

$('.selected').change(function(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        total += parseFloat($(`#amount_${e.target.value}`).val().replaceAll(",",""))
        showForm()
    } else {
        $("#selectAll").prop("checked", false)
        total -= parseFloat($(`#amount_${e.target.value}`).val().replaceAll(",",""))
        hideForm()
    }
    $('#request_total').text(numberWithCommas(total.toFixed(2)))
})
</scirpt>
```

But the code returned 0.00 after selecting checkbox. What may be going wrong ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: Did you run the javascript code through the browsers debugger?

Comment: @  RiggsFolly. Yes

Comment: So what did it tell you? Does it run? Where does it do something wrong? Do you get any error messages .....

Comment: @ RiggsFolly. Not found any errors

Comment: So did you step it line by line, checking the contents of variables as you go to see where you made a mistake?

Comment: @ RiggsFolly. I also did that. Didn't find any mistake.

Comment: Thats rather difficult to believe !!!!!

Comment: @ RiggsFolly, No. That's true. Sometimes It may be missed some points even I did go line by line. Can you view through and help to find the mistakes.

Comment: When you say _I want to get sum of amounts under Total row_ you actually mean you want to _SUM the amounts under `Total` **column**_! But I dont see a __Total Column__. Please be more specific

Comment: @ RiggsFolly. No. There is not available "Total" column. There is a row named as "Total". So, I want to get sum in this row. Pls. see on <tfoot>
        <tr class="" style="background-color: #00cc99 !important;">
            <td colspan="<?= $type ? 5 : 6 ?>">Total</td>
            <td id="request_total"  class="text-right" ></td>            
            <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

Comment: Ahh, I see now! Ok, so there are no values in that Row and no fields or anything to add up?? I am afraid I am now even more confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248859/discussion-between-mcit-trends-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: I'm also equally confused why this question was tagged with php, mysql, codeigniter (all server side programming languages), when the question is about javascript...

Comment: @ Shadow. Really, That was a mistake. If so, pls give me an answer to my question.